# How to access s3 link i got from other people

Tags: amazon-s3

I have this sql on s3 link

```
s3://fff-cans/crm/full/production_20190214.sql.gz
```

how can I access this ? it only gives blank page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an IAM key setup to access it too. Once you have that there are several ways, including the Amazon Command Line toolset:
https://aws.amazon.com/cli/
Which you would use like so:

```
 aws s3 cp s3://fff-cans/crm/full/production_20190214.sql.gz .
```

(After installing hte IAM credentials)

You can use the web interface http://aws.amazon.com Which you will need a username and password.

There are also several UI tools you can use. Like http://s3browser.com/ and https://cyberduck.io/

Comment: can I get the file without accessing the aws ?

Comment: tried install cli and type the command u suggested but it gave me error saying error too few arguments

Comment: S3 is on AWS so by definition no. What did you type?

Comment: I already got the file  , thanks to your answer ! I have the Key so I didn't need to login to aws console. just typed the credentials in aws cli